# questions on AVFrameSideData and motion vector

Tags: c, ffmpeg

When I executed the following code:

```
    AVFrameSideData* avfsd=NULL;
    avfsd = av_frame_get_side_data(frame, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);
    if(avfsd->data != NULL)
        printf("avfsd->data != NULL\n");
```

I got a segmentation fault. It seemed to me that avfsd is not allowed to access data field. But when I look up the documentation of AVFrameSideData, I found:

```
typedef struct AVFrameSideData {
        enum AVFrameSideDataType type;
        uint8_t *data;
        int      size;
        AVDictionary *metadata;
    } AVFrameSideData;
```

why can't I access `unint8_t *data` through: `avfsd->data`? Frankly, avfsd is not Null. The following is some debugging infomation:

```
(gdb) print avfsd 
$5 = <optimized out>
(gdb) print *avfsd
value has been optimized out
(gdb) print avfsd->data
value has been optimized out
(gdb) print frame->side_data 
$6 = (AVFrameSideData **) 0x1bc4000
```

Btw, is the data here the data of motion vector of the frame? Why is it so short: see what I got from gdb:

```
(gdb) print frame->side_data[0]->type
$2 = AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS
(gdb) print frame->side_data[0]->data   
$1 = (uint8_t *) 0x1c32540 "\377\377\377\377\020\020\006"
```

I thought motion vector should be kind of a long chain. But from above...why is it that short?

Comment: Where does it crash? (Run "bt" in your debugger.)

Comment: Hi, nice to see you again:-) I don't know why it crashes. It happened when I tried to access the data field ("avfsd->data") of a non-null struct pointer("avfsd"), which had been said to be optimized out in GDB. see above i added some gdb info...

Comment: Compile your software with -O0 -g, then all information should be available.

Comment: @Ronald S. Bultje it really worked! not only in gdb but in my software there is no segmentation fault any more!! can you tell me what kind of role does -O0 here play?

Comment: @Ronald S. Bultje Is the "avfsd->data" here the actual data of a motion vector? It does not look like a motion vector: a motion vector should be something like a matrix?...

Comment: It's a struct AVMotionVector (https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/motion__vector_8h_source.html). -O0 simply disables optimizations, it shouldn't prevent crashes... Do note your example code checked only avfsd->data != NULL, not avfsd != NULL...

Comment: Are you saying "\377\377\377\377\020\020\006" is a struct!? How can it be. Or do you have a way to convert this octal data chain into a struct?

Comment: #include "libavutil/motion_vector.h" and then struct AVMotionVector *mv = (struct AVMotionVector *) avfsd->data; int n_mvs = avfsd->size / sizeof(struct AVMotionVector); and then iterate over mv[] with idx between 0 and n_mvs.

Comment: sounds cool! I'll try it out. Thanks a lot!